# Why do I need to put the function inside a setState method for it to work?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

When a socket emits an event from the server side the App reloads for some reason and posts is emptied out.  But when I define the function inside the setPosts it works perfectly.  Why is this?

```
const App = () => {
  let [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  let [posts, setPosts] = useState({})
  console.log('app')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('use effect')

    socket.on('post', (post) => {


      // THIS DOES NOT WORK:
      // let newPosts = { ...posts }
      // newPosts[post._id] = post
      // setPosts(newPosts)

      //THIS WORKS
      setPosts((posts) => {
        let newPosts = { ...posts }
        newPosts[post._id] = post
        return newPosts
      })
    })



    async function getUser() {
      let user = await actions.getUser()
      if (user) {
        setUser(user?.data)
      }
    }

    getUser()

    actions
      .getAllPosts()
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('WE GOT ALL POSTSTFOM API', res.data)
        const postsById = {}
        for (let post of res.data) {
          postsById[post._id] = post
        }
        console.log('wired')
        setPosts(postsById)
        //filterPosts(res.data)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err))

    return () => {
      socket.off('post')
    }
  }, [])
```

Comment: Eventhandlers are functions. But did you check if there is any other issue? At what stage is the reload happening during debugging? While setting state?

Answer (score 0):

This is how enclosures work in javascript. When you use a non-functional state update you are referencing the `posts` state value (`{}`) from the render cycle the callback was instantiated in, i.e. the initial render when the effect callback ran when mounted (*note the empty dependency array*). It's a stale enclosure of the `posts` state value.

When using a functional state update you are accessing and updating from the previous state, ***not*** the state from the previous render cycle (or enclosure).